# Typesetting Unicode characters with XeTeX and fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode

Upon advice I started to use `XeTeX` to typeset Unicode characters. It did not work.

Then I started to use `fontspec`. No output was generated for ∃.

What else should I do to make it work?

Comment: very few fonts have every Unicode character so you need to specify a font that has the character (otherwise it will warn you in the log about the missing character in the font you are using)

Answer (score 2):

∃ is a math symbol (U+2203), so use a math font and math environment. You can e.g. use unicode-math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$ ∃ $
\end{document}
```